# How to create an instance using an existing contract and deploy the instance as a new contract

Tags: ethereum

I want to complete a blockchain-based voting system. I use truffle compile and truffle migrate to compile and deploy the template contract.The contract content is as follows

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract VotingSystem {
    struct Ballot {
        string title;
        string[] options;
        uint256 deadline;
        bool isOpen;
        mapping(string => uint256) voteCounts;
    }

    Ballot public latestBallot; 

    event BallotCreated(address indexed creator, string title, uint256 deadline);

    function createBallot(string memory _title, string[] memory _options, uint256 _deadline) public {
        require(_options.length >= 2 && _options.length <= 10, "Number of options must be between 2 and 10");
        require(_deadline > block.timestamp, "Deadline must be in the future");

        latestBallot.title = _title;
        latestBallot.options = _options;
        latestBallot.deadline = _deadline;
        latestBallot.isOpen = true;

        emit BallotCreated(msg.sender, _title, _deadline);
    }

    function castVote(string memory _option) public {
        require(latestBallot.isOpen, "Voting is closed");
        require(block.timestamp < latestBallot.deadline, "Voting has ended");

        bool validOption = false;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < latestBallot.options.length; i++) {
            if (keccak256(bytes(latestBallot.options[i])) == keccak256(bytes(_option))) {
                validOption = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        require(validOption, "Invalid option");

        latestBallot.voteCounts[_option]++;
    }

    function finalizeBallot() public {
        require(block.timestamp >= latestBallot.deadline, "Voting is still ongoing");

        latestBallot.isOpen = false;
    }

    function getOptions() public view returns (string[] memory) {
        return latestBallot.options;
    }

    function getBallotTitle() public view returns (string memory) {
        return latestBallot.title;
    }

    function getDeadline() public view returns (uint256) {
        return latestBallot.deadline;
    }

    function getCurrentTimestamp() public view returns (uint256) {
        return block.timestamp;
    }

    function getWinner() public view returns (string memory) {
        require(!latestBallot.isOpen, "Voting is still ongoing");
        require(block.timestamp >= latestBallot.deadline, "Voting has not ended yet");

        uint256 maxVotes = 0;
        string memory winner;
        
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < latestBallot.options.length; i++) {
            uint256 votes = latestBallot.voteCounts[latestBallot.options[i]];
            if (votes > maxVotes) {
                maxVotes = votes;
                winner = latestBallot.options[i];
            }
        }
        return winner;
    }
}
```

Then I use the following code to call and deploy the new contract：

```
app.post('/createVote', async (req, res) => {
    const formData = req.body;
    const voteTitle = formData.voteTitle;
    const numOptions = formData.numOptions;
    const options = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= numOptions; i++) {
        options.push(formData['option' + i]);
    }
    const deadlineTimestamp = new Date(formData.deadline).getTime();

    console.log(voteTitle);
    console.log(options);
    console.log(deadlineTimestamp);

    try {
        newContractInstance = await new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI)
            .deploy({
                data: contractBytecode,
                arguments: [voteTitle, options, deadlineTimestamp] 
            })
            .send({
                from: callerAddress, 
                gas: 1500000, 
                gasPrice: '30000000000' 
            }); 
    
        console.log('new contract address：', newContractInstance.options.address);
        res.json({ success: true, contractAddress: newContractInstance.options.address });

        insertDataIntoBallots(callerAddress, newContractInstance.options.address, voteTitle, formData.deadline);
        const options_test = await newContractInstance.methods.getOptions().call();
        const title_test = await newContractInstance.methods.getBallotTitle().call();
        const deadline_test = await newContractInstance.methods.getDeadline().call();
        console.log('options:', options_test);
        console.log('title:', title_test);
        console.log('deadline:', deadline_test);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('部署合约时发生错误：', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to deploy contract' });
    }
});
```

But when printing the output, the content is always empty?
Assuming that the contract template is A, does the following code create an instance of template A and deploy it as a new contract? But in the records of ganache, there are only records of creating contracts but no records of calling contracts?
How to solve this problem, thank you very much

I have not modified the ABI. The new contract and the template contract share the same ABI;